# Python win32com.client Dispatch and Create Shorcut Methods

Tags: python, shortcut, win32com

I want to ask few questions about `win32com.client`.

1. What does `DisPatch` do? It returns `COMObject wscript.shell`. What exactly is this?

   ```
   shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("wscript.shell")
   ```
2. And why do we use it while creating shortcut.

   ```
   shortcutcut = shell.CreateShortcut('shortcut.lnk')
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`win32com.client.Dispatch` creates a ActiveX/COM object. The argument is the so-called program ID. Another example of program ID is "Excel.Application" which would be used to create an instance of Excel. In your case you are creating a `wscript.shell` object.

The program ID is mapped to a DLL on the system by the registry. The object is instantiated through a number of well-known export methods.

Apparently, one of the methods of a wscript.shell object is CreateShortcut. Why you are using a wscript.shell to do this, I can't say.